# react render --How to render 2 props with map function in discussion app

Tags: reactjs, function, firebase, dictionary, object

having trouble with dicussion app. I can render only header or post at a given time.Having trouble how to render in thread.jsx.
This app is in react and firebase.
Pls suggest me how to fix this.
I think map function in post is not right.how to write a object with map function. do I need to write object as a prop?

thread.jsx--------

```
postEditor.jsx-----
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './DpostEditor.css';

export default class PostEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state= {

    newPostBody:'',
  newHeaderBody:'',
    };
 this. handlePostHeaderInputChange=this.handlePostHeaderInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePostEditorInputChange = this.handlePostEditorInputChange.bind(this);
    this.createPost = this.createPost.bind(this);
}


  handlePostEditorInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({

      newPostBody : e.target.value,

    })
  }
  handlePostHeaderInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({

      newHeaderBody : e.target.value,

    })
  }

  createPost() {
  this.props.addPost(this.state.newPostBody);


  this.setState({

  newPostBody: '',
  newHeaderBody:'',
  });

  }

    render() {
    return(
     <div className= "panel panel-default post-editor">
          <div className="panel-body">
            <textarea className= "form-control post-header-input" value={this.state.newHeaderBody} onChange={this. handlePostHeaderInputChange }/>
            <textarea className= "form-control post-editor-input" value={this.state.newPostBody} onChange={this.handlePostEditorInputChange }/>
            <button className= "btn btn-success post-editor-button" onClick= {this.createPost}> Post </button>

          </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Post.jsx------

```
import React from 'react';
import './Dpost.css';



 const Post= (props)=> (

    <div className=" panel panel-default post-body">
       <div className="panel-heading">
            {props.postBody.map((header,postType,idx)=>(
                <div>
                <div> {header} </div>
                 <div> {postType} </div>
                </div>
            ))
            }
       </div>


    </div>      

);

export default Post;
```

Comment: Do you see any errors/output? This doesn't look right `onChange={this. handlePostHeaderInputChange }`, it should be without spaces

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the map function is wrong. You're passing 3 parameters that don't match the ones the map array helper uses.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Scroll to the **Parameters** section to check them. Right now you're passing the parameters of the post and not the array.

Perhaps you should try something like this:

```js
{props.postBody.map((post)=>(
  <div key={post.idx}>// remember the key in a map iterator
    <div> {post.header} </div>
    <div> {post.postType} </div>
  </div>
))}
```

But this depends on the structure of your `props.postBody` array. The code above assumes that is a collection of posts.

---

**Edit**

Considering the fact that your props may be undefined at some point you use a conditional logic to run the array map helper:

```js
{props.postBody ? props.postBody.map((post)=>(
  <div key={post.idx}>// remember the key in a map iterator
    <div> {post.header} </div>
    <div> {post.postType} </div>
  </div>
)) : null}
```

Comment: Still getting the error.TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined